# Scroll bar jumps back to the top

Tags: css, user-interface, scrollbar

I am using Material UI list, but whenever I select a list item the scrollbar jumps back to the top.

This is my style:

```js
liststyle: {
  background: "#FFF",
  overflowY: "scroll",
  maxHeight: "75%",
}
```

Any idea how to fix this ?